# How to copy a specific file from Raspbian SD Card to Windows

Tags: raspbian

Ago 2-3 weeks I saved a couple of files to my Raspberry Pi SD Card , and then gave the RPi to my dad (he used his SDCard , I kept mine) , and now I need those files but I don't have any RPi left , is there any posibility to take those without a RPi or I need one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it is not possible to read out the sd card without a special software. Because Linux used another file system than Windows.

The best way is to download a 'Live CD' and temporarily boot that on your Windows computer. With this way you can run a Linux without installing it on you machine. With Linux it is easy to access the entire SD card. Search your files and store this on a stick.

When you're done you take the CD out, reboot and go back to your Windows.

Comment: So if i make a virtual machine with ubuntu I have a chance to get those  files?

Comment: You can also use a virtual machine, if the vm software support sd card mounting. Then you can also use this method.

Comment: Thanks for the answers